# Unable to prepare a maven release with ERROR

Tags: java, apache, maven

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project SampleProject: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'

```
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:318)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:414)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:357)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:290)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.execute(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:240)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.ReleaseExecutionException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRunGoalsPhase.execute(AbstractRunGoalsPhase.java:91)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.RunPrepareGoalsPhase.execute(RunPrepareGoalsPhase.java:44)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:234)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:169)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:286)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.MavenExecutorException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.InvokerMavenExecutor.executeGoals(InvokerMavenExecutor.java:433)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.AbstractMavenExecutor.executeGoals(AbstractMavenExecutor.java:114)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRunGoalsPhase.execute(AbstractRunGoalsPhase.java:85)
```

Here is a code fragment of pom.xml

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>developer</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <modules>
            <!-- Module dedicated for deployment activities. -->
            <module>deployment</module>
        </modules>
        <build>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                        <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                        <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${release.plugin.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                        <tagBase>https://scm.mycompany.com/tags/test</tagBase>
                        <tagNameFormat>test-@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this commands if an error ocurred in you maven realease.

> `mvn release:prepare -Dresume=false`
>
> Alternatively, you can use:
>
> `mvn release:clean release:prepare`

Check the [maven doc](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add **checkModificationExclude** in **maven-release-plugin**

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <goals>install</goals>
                <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                <checkModificationExcludes>
                    <checkModificationExclude>pom.xml</checkModificationExclude>
                    <checkModificationExclude>**</checkModificationExclude>
                </checkModificationExcludes>
            </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Please elaborate more on your answer. Providing just a block of code, is not the right way to help someone. Explain the error and your solution to help the author and any other potential visitor